# Optimizing calls to new for a vector of pointers?

Tags: c++, vector

I have a vector of Foo*. What I put inside is always Foo*, there is no polymorphism.

I use a vector of pointers because I tried a list and it kept crashing. I need to be able to use the pointers in other places so a regular vector of Foo would not work.

ex: b.add(&myRegularVec[6]); //when I add more this pointer wont be valid.

The problem is that I would need the reserve capability of vector.  Right now, I have a function like this:

```
void addRange(int quantity)
{
   for (int i = 0; i < quantity; ++i)
        {
            Foo* obj = new Foo(i);
             m_theVector.push_back(obj);
             b.add(obj);
        }
}
```

Unfortunately, this calls new a whole lot, and the profiler says it is the bottleneck.

I can not invalidate pointers ex: to grow I would need to redo new[].

What could I do to avoid so many calls to new and make it faster?

Thanks

Comment: What do you mean with this phrase: `need to be able to use the pointers in other places so a regular vector of Foo would not work.`?

Comment: Also, do the `Foo`'s really _have_ to be __initialized__ with `i`? It makes optimization hard, it would be much easier to use default initialization and then do something like `foo.set_value` for each `foo`.

Comment: ex: b.add(&myRegularVec[6]); //when I add more this pointer wont be valid.

Comment: @Milo: not if you reserve enough to prevent resizing.

Comment: @Irfy exactly, that is my problem.

Comment: I do not see a solution, depending on what Foo is indeed. Each new makes a new object and it is the way it should be, but as said, it depends on Foo; if it is a bottleneck you need to change something before in your code, so that you can get `Foo(i)` as fast as possible. If you do it at a one-time initialization point, I do not see why you need to fix this "bottleneck"

Comment: @Milo: Do you ever remove elements?  If so, do you ever remove elements from the middle? or just the ends?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use a `deque<Foo>` instead of a `vector<Foo*>`, since a deque won't invalidate the pointers as it grows the container.

Comment: This is the right solution.  Good locality like `vector`, but without moving items during resize.

Answer (score 0):

> I have a vector of Foo*. What I put inside is always Foo*, there is no polymorphism.

If there is no polymorphism, then what you need a vector of `Foo`, not `Foo*`.  You don't have correct reason to use `Foo*` in your program. So forget what you're currently doing, and start afresh with `std::vector<Foo>`:

```
std::vector<Foo> m_theVector;
```

then do this:

```
void addRange(int quantity)
{
   for (int i = 0; i < quantity; ++i)
   {
      m_theVector.push_back(Foo(quantity));
   }
}
```

If you fear of reallocation for whatever reason, then use `std::list` which doesn't reallocate the old items.

Comment: But I need to add these foos to containers ex: a render container. The vector will invalidate them when it reallocates.

Comment: @Milo: What is the problem then?

Comment: I would have to reserve enough to meet any needs, but I dont know how much that is, unless I use a memory-wasting amount.